# How to correctly push a tag after changing the commit that it points at?

Tags: git

I've tagged a commit, then pushed the tag to origin. Later I changed which commit is tagged using `git tag -f`, and pushed the tag to origin again. However the origin still has the tag pointing at the initial commit.

How can I get the two back in sync again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should you do when you tag a wrong commit and you would want to
>   re-tag?
>
> If you never pushed anything out, just re-tag it. Use "-f" to replace
>   the old one. And you’re done.
>
> But if you have pushed things out (or others could just read your
>   repository directly), then others will have already seen the old tag.
>   In that case you can do one of two things:
>
> The sane thing. Just admit you screwed up, and use a different name. Others have already seen one tag-name, and if you keep the same
>   name, you may be in the situation that two people both have "version
>   X", but they actually have different "X"'s. So just call it "X.1" and
>   be done with it.
>
> The insane thing. You really want to call the new version "X" too, even though others have already seen the old one. So just use git tag
>   -f again, as if you hadn’t already published the old one.

You can find this information (and some more) in the [git-tag manual page, section "On Re-tagging"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_re_tagging).

Comment: Thanks for the link. The actual answer is to execute the following on each checkout that pulled the original tag: `git tag -d tag-name`. The next pull will then pull the correct tag.

Comment: That may workaround the problem in a closed environment or a small team but I'd not call that a "solution" for a public repository or a large team, since you can't control every clone. Just doublecheck everything is right before commiting and pushing tags and if that happens again, just deal with the fact that you made a mistake and use another tag name. Without knowing more about your team workflow or repo usage I can't recommend you anything else.

Comment: OK sure; the entire section you linked to was helpful. What I meant was that the answer to "how to get them back in sync" was to delete the out of date tag and pull again. Might be worth writing that in your answer in case someone else stumbles across it.

Answer (score 0):

```
git push --tags -f
```

Tags are not made to be changed. So you have to force that, if you really want it, both locally (`git tag -f`) and when pushing. If you find yourself doing this a lot, you should consider using branches instead, they are made for changing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do it. I just get an "everything up to date" message, but the tags are still out of sync. And yeah, this is a one-off.